# How to include $ sign as string?

Tags: bash, variable, echo

I want to create multiple files with a common template, problem is there have "$(variable)" in the template, which should be written with $ sign. 
for example, I want `output is $job_ID` from

```
echo "output is $job_ID"
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

You can escape special characters with a backslash, such as:

```
echo " output is \$job_ID"
```

or use single quotes instead

```
echo ' output is $job_ID'
```